# I want to fetch data from cache (storage) in frontend

Tags: javascript, vue.js, caching, nuxt.js

In order to increase the performance of my website, I want to get frequently used data with only 1 request at the beginning and save it in a storage.

I used localstorage before but it was not dynamic enough. Nuxt's state structure was insufficient. I am looking for other solutions. A mechanism that will not be deleted after the page is refreshed, where I can store the data in the frontend.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not dynamic enough"? What do you need to do that localStorage can't?

Comment: Changes made to localstorage by one component were affecting the other component (for example, localstorage changed in one component was not updated in the other component). Maybe there is a solution, but I'm looking for a cleaner way.

Comment: localstorage is managed by the browser, outside of your app.  it sounds more like you update localstorage in one component and haven't yet fetched the updated value in the second component.  It's not a piece of reactive state so you won't get an updated value without checking for it yourself.  There are [strategies](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-make-localstorage-reactive-in-vue-js/#) and [libraries](https://vueuse.org/core/useStorage/) that can make localstorage in your app reactive if that's what you need.

Comment: Maybe you should make a simple example that shows what did not work. Sounds like you either load in data wrong or reference it in a non shared way. It is hard for us to guess why your solution does not work.